# Would like to get confirmation for how I understand tight coupling between 2 objects

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Does this code below mean that all vehicle objects will always have 6 litter engines? because the vehicle class is tightly coupled with an engine which we always construct as part of the vehicle object?

```
public class Vehicle {

    public void crankIgnition(){
        Engine sixLiterEngine = new Engine("6 Liter Engine");
        sixLiterEngine.startEngine();
        System.out.println("Vehicle is running");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask:

> Does this code below mean that all vehicle objects will always have 6 litter engines?

```
public class Vehicle {

    public void crankIgnition(){
        Engine sixLiterEngine = new Engine("6 Liter Engine");
        sixLiterEngine.startEngine();
        System.out.println("Vehicle is running");
    }
}
```

---

---

No, this code means that Vehicle objects will have **no** engines. Note that you declare your Engine variable in the constructor and so it has very limited scope to the constructor and in fact exists in the constructor only. As soon as the constructor ends, the Vehicle will have on Engine, nothing.

Perhaps you're asking about this situation:

```
public class Vehicle {
    private Engine;

    public void crankIgnition(){
        engine = new Engine("6 Liter Engine");
        engine.startEngine();
        System.out.println("Vehicle is running");
    }
}
```

in which case yes, Vehicle is tightly coupled to Engine.

Comment: You meant to define a member variable at the class level called engine  right? And then use it in the crankIgnition method correct?

Comment: @Tazo: without a field, your Vehicle class has no *state*. I mean that your current code is not an example of anything useful.

Comment: And is it tightly coupled to just Engine? or the 6 liter engine in your example?

Comment: @Tazo: there is no type "6 liter engine". Rather you an instance of the Engine class whose constructor parameter String says something.

Comment: okay, but is it always that one instance for all of the vehicle objects in the application? or each vehicle object will contain their own instances of engine?

Comment: Each Vehicle instance will have its own Engine instance, but they will all have the same state, as my code is currently written.

Comment: How would all vehicle instances be coupled with the same exact engine instance? I thought that's what is being achieved in the code I mentioned.

Comment: @Tazo: please clarify your last statement.

Comment: Sorry, hit chat button by mistake -- please show your updated information as I don't see it yet.

Comment: i meant my comment. I updated my earlier statement in the comment